# Can't convert ICollection<t> to IEnumerable<t>

Tags: c#, expression, ienumerable, expression-trees, icollection

I am building the expression tree:

> {x => x.principal_info.First().agent_for_property_info}

It works as expected.

In fact, I need to convert it to `IEnumerable` instead of `ICollection` as you can see here.

Here is the method that works:

```
public Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<K>>> GetGenericExpression<T, K>(bool first = false, params string[] properties)
    {
        var expression = GetNavigationPropertySelector<T, K>(typeof(T), first, properties);

        var expRight = (Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<K>>>)expression;

        return expRight;
    }
```

In the expression, I get the valid lambda expression:

> {x => x.principal_info.First().agent_for_property_info}

When I am casting:

```
var expRight = (Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<K>>>)expression;
```

I get an exception:

```
Unable to cast object of 
type 
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[SomeModel1,
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[SomeModel]]]' 
to type 
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[SomeModel1
,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SomeModel]]]'.
```

I knew that `ICollection` inherits from `IEnumerable` assuming, that it something pretty easy to fix.

I researched a lot but didn't find the solution how to cast `ICollection<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` or if this even possible?

In fact, the compiler can cast it implicitly as these lines are valid:

```
var queryData1 = new QueryData<contact_info, IEnumerable<property_info>>()
                {
                    WhereClause = expression,
                    SelectClause = info => info.principal_info.First().agent_for_property_info
                };
```

As this expression is a type of `ICollection`:

> info => info.principal_info.First().agent_for_property_info

Comment: @Adriani6 our questions differ in some cases:
1) The point was to convert from IEnumerable to ICollection (my case: vice versa)
2) They are trying to convert actual datasets - in my case I need the expression of the right type.

Comment: You're correct, I've retracted my vote :)

Comment: No, you're not trying to convert a `ICollection<T>` to an `IEnumerable<T>`. You're trying to convert (to within a handwave or two) a *delegate* that will produce an `ICollection<T>` You don't need to cast *it*, you need to cast its result when it has produced one, which suggests you're going to be writing (partial) expression trees here to achieve what you want (if that's the route you want to go down)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yep, you are right. Just casting the result type.

Comment: @DanielLoudon The lambda-expression doesn't have extension methods like 'select' neither Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<K>>>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours of researching, trying different approaches, I came up with Idea, trying to overcome this exception. So the workaround I use was the suggestion from the comments:

> x => x.principal_info.First().agent_for_property_info.Select(x4 => x4)

Here what I have added while building an expression:

```
var result1 = Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Enumerable), "Select", new Type[] { elementResultType, elementResultType },
                    resultProperty, resultExpr);
```

I actually didn't find the solution, but if someone will encounter such problem, maybe this answer could save his time.

Comment: I couldn't use your workaround, but I have to salute you for coming back and sharing your findings with us!